# Единственное число слова «брызги»

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, существительные, единственное-множественное-число

> Молодой человек, смывавший кровь в водосток, ловко управлялся со шлангом — ни одной лишней **брызги**.
> [И. Рэнкин. Плоть и кровь](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=34731&p=72) (перевод с английского Григория Крылова)

В одних словарях утверждается, что формы единственного числа не используются; в других — *варьируется **ударение*** в единственном числе (или вообще не указано).
Хотелось бы знать ваше мнение — как же правильно?

Answer (score 3):

В старой литературе есть примеры с выражением "ни одной брызги" (поиск по книгам в сети позволяет легко их найти), которым, возможно, и ограничивается употребление слова в единственном числе. В быту чаще употребляется родительный падеж множественного числа (брызг), который позволяет видеть, что это существительное женского рода.

> *Ни одной брызги* не перелетело через борт на палубу. *(из писем
>   Белинского)*

Comment: Форма "брызгой" встречается чаще и в самых разнообразных выражениях. Не только у Маяковского, Пастернака, Брюсова, Асеева и т.п., но и у современных авторов. (Я не возражаю, просто поленился оформить это предложение отдельным ответом :)

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, не все словари признают ед. ч. слова **брызги.** Так, например, словарь Ушакова говорит, что ед. ч. нет. В словаре Ожегова вооюще не упоминается о ед.ч. Однако словарь Кузнецова все же признает ед. ч. 
БРЫЗГИ, брызг; мн. **(ед. брызга, -и; ж.).** 1. Капли жидкости, разлетающиеся от удара, всплеска и т.п.
**2. только мн.: брызги, брызг. чего**. Мелкие частицы вещества, разлетающиеся от удара в разные стороны. Б. осколков. Б. снежной пыли. 
Грамота.ру указывает, что ед. ч. малоупотребительно.

Марина Королева то же говорит о том, что ед. ч. нет. 
Но все же придется согласится с Грамотой.ру.

В Национальном корпусе удалось найти  8 примеров со словом **брызга.**

**Маслянистая брызга упала мне на руку, я тут же ее вытер о куртку.** **[Нина Садур. Сад (1994)]**

**Роза! Она ― брызга от магмы! ― Ты знал это?! [Нина Садур. Занебесный мальчик (1992)]**
**Небо было бирюзово-розовым, и самолет казался на нем как грязная брызга. [Константин Воробьев. Крик (1962)]**

Answer (score 1):

Молодой человек, смывавший кровь в водосток, ловко управлялся со шлангом — **ни одной лишней капли.**

**Не во всех словарях "брызги" есть, и это очень правильно.** Брызги ― это разлетающиеся мелкие частицы чего-либо (водяные, снежные, огненные), их много, но при этом в отдельности они уже имеют свое  название: **капля, искра.**

В современных текстах  это слово воспринимается как  авторский неологизм (или  архаизм, если оно использовалось раньше).

Если оно даже остается нормированным (отмечается в некоторых словарях), то  может применяться **как средство художественной выразительности** (Роза! Она ― брызга от магмы!), но для обычного использования  (*брызга вместо капли*) не очень подходит.